# Find the location of a cell that matches a string in the entire worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

Suppose I want to find the cell that contains the string "XYXY" in the entire worksheet (say it is in cells(100,35)) and change the value of the cell next to it in the next column (e.g. cells(100,36)). How can this be done efficiently?

I know of

```
    Set CellPV = ActiveSheet.Cells.Find(What:="XYXY", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
```

which does find the cell effectively, however does not show location/Range; when I use `MsgBox(CellPV)` , it gives me the value of the cell, as opposed to its location in the worksheet.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to know `CellPV`'s address on the worksheet.

Just use [`Range.Offset`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.offset):

```
If Not CellPV Is Nothing Then 'Test if Find was successful
   CellPV.Offset(,1).Value = "foo"
End If
```

If you really do want to know `cellPV`s address, then:

```
MsgBox CellPV.Address 'no parentheses here
```